# How to exclude empty rows while sorting in material ui datagrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a scenario, in which I'm getting the empty rows in the response, I'm using material UI's data grid component, So how do I ignore those empty rows while sorting?
Any suggestion would be Appreciable, Thanks!!

Here is the Example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-moser-v9jq6z?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You mean deleting the row which doesn't have `firstName`?

Comment: No Bro, it should be placed at the Bottom while Sorting!

Comment: Could you please add more points about your expected result? Do you need to have the rows without `firstName` at the last?

Comment: Sure Bro, when I click on the sort icon of first name column, it should sort the column of firstname in Ascending order, so Arya should display on the first row & All Blank rows should be displayed at the Bottom!

Comment: @programmers_view Just do this:  rows={rows.filter(res=>res.firstName!==null)} inside Datagrid component.

Answer (score 1):

You asked a little while ago so I'm presuming you've found a solution.
Annoyingly the sort direction isn't passed to the sortComparator in a simple way through via the GridComparatorFn function.

However, you can get at it through the api on the cellParams parameters.

So my solution is to set the `sortComparator` on your GridColDef like:

```
 {
    field: "firstName",
    headerName: "First name",
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
    sortComparator: nullHandlingSortComparator,
  },
```

Where `nullHandlingSortComparator` is the function below. Using `gridStringOrNumberComparator` imported from `@mui/x-data-grid-pro`

```js
export const nullHandlingSortComparator: GridComparatorFn = (
  v1,
  v2,
  cellParams1,
  cellParams2
): number => {
  if (v1 == null || v2 == null) {
    if (v1 == v2) return 0;
    else {
      const sortModel = cellParams1.api.getSortModel();
      const sortColumn = sortModel.find(
        (sm: GridSortItem) => sm.field == cellParams1.field
      );
      if (sortColumn && sortColumn.sort == "desc") {
        if (v1 == null) return -1;
        else return 1;
      } else {
        if (v1 == null) return 1;
        else return -1;
      }
    }
  } else {
    return gridStringOrNumberComparator(v1, v2, cellParams1, cellParams2);
  }
};
```

Have you stumbled across a better solution in the meantime?

Comment: Sorry bro, but I'm not using @mui/x-data-grid-pro! thanks for the suggestion @JamesLevett

Comment: import { GridColDef, GridComparatorFn,gridStringOrNumberComparator} from '@mui/x-data-grid';

Answer (score 0):

You can also add any condition in filter method to your array.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

const columns = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 90 },
  {
    field: "firstName",
    headerName: "First name",
    width: 150,
    editable: true
  },
  {
    field: "lastName",
    headerName: "Last name",
    width: 150,
    editable: true
  },
  {
    field: "age",
    headerName: "Age",
    type: "number",
    width: 110,
    editable: true
  },
  {
    field: "fullName",
    headerName: "Full name",
    description: "This column has a value getter and is not sortable.",
    sortable: false,
    width: 160,
    valueGetter: (params) =>
      `${params.row.firstName || ""} ${params.row.lastName || ""}`
  }
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, lastName: "Snow", firstName: null, age: 35 },
  { id: 2, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: null, age: 42 },
  { id: 3, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Jaime", age: 45 },
  { id: 4, lastName: "Stark", firstName: "Arya", age: 16 },
  { id: 5, lastName: "Targaryen", firstName: "Daenerys", age: null },
  { id: 6, lastName: "Melisandre", firstName: null, age: 150 },
  { id: 7, lastName: "Clifford", firstName: "Ferrara", age: 44 },
  { id: 8, lastName: "Frances", firstName: "Rossini", age: 36 },
  { id: 9, lastName: "Roxie", firstName: "Harvey", age: 65 }
];

export default function DataGridDemo() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows.filter(res=>res.firstName!==null)}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
        disableSelectionOnClick
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the Answer bro, but i also want to display empty rows at bottom,  I don't want to remove them!

Comment: Your component already has these features. while sorting it comes to the bottom. Either you can call another datagrid with rows={rows.filter(res=>res.firstName===null)} for empty rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
 way to write custom sort , also handles null and space:
    
    nullSpaceHandlingSortComparator = (
        v1,
        v2,
        cellParams1,
        cellParams2
      ) => {
        const sortModel = cellParams1.api.getSortModel();
        const sortColumn = sortModel.find(
              (sm) => sm.field == cellParams1.field
        );
        if (sortColumn && sortColumn.sort == "desc") {
            if ((v1 == null && v2 == null) || (v1 == "" && v2 == "")) {
            return -1;
            }
            if ((v1 == null) || (v1 == "")) {
            return -1;
            }
            if ((v2 == null) || (v2 == "")) {
            return 1;
            }
          return v1 - v2; 
        }else{
    
          if ((v1 == null && v2 == null) || (v1 == "" && v2 == "")) {
              return 0;
          }
          if ((v1 == null) || (v1 == "")) {
              return 1;
          }
          if ((v2 == null) || (v2 == "")) {
              return -1;
          }
          return v1 - v2;  
        }
      };

 { field: "controlTriggerLowerVal", headerName: "Lower Trigger", width: 150 ,type: "number",headerAlign: "left",
                  renderCell: (cellValues) => {
                    return  <> {cellValues.row.calculateLowerTrigger} </>;
                  },flex:1,align: 'left',
                  sortComparator: this.nullSpaceHandlingSortComparator,
                  }
```